Can std::enable_if methods be defined outside of a class
Is there a syntax that allows for method1 to be defined outside of the class or is that not SFINAE friendly?
#include <type_traits>

template <int TClass>
struct SampleClass {
    // This definition compiles just fine
    template <int TMethod = TClass>
    typename std::enable_if<TMethod == 0, void>::type
    method0() {}

    // Declaration
    template <int TMethod = TClass>
    typename std::enable_if<TMethod == 1, void>::type
    method1();
};

// This does not compile
template <int TClass>
template <int TMethod = TClass>
typename std::enable_if<TMethod == 1, void>::type
SampleClass<TClass>::method1() {}

int main() { return 0; }

Using GCC 10.2.1, error:
foo.cpp:20:30: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'typename std::enable_if<(TMethod == 1), void>::type SampleClass<TClass>::method1()'
   20 | SampleClass<TClass>::method1() {}
      |                              ^


Please include the error message.

Please don't omit #include. Why do you make other users guess what you missed?

The entire error message is much clearer https://godbolt.org/z/neG9PPd63 Just remove the = TClass from the definition.

The reason you include stuff like #include is because you don't know what is going wrong.  If you knew what was going wrong, you could work out what you can safely exclude; but then why ask the question?  So you should aim for a [mcve], code that can be copy/pasted and reproduces your error, as best you can.  Which includes "obviously not the problem" code like #includes, because messing those up can give strange errors, and because it makes replicating your problem easier for other people to debug.

In the out of class definition, you cannot reintroduce the default value TMethod = TClass. It is just like a function with a default parameter: you define it only in declaration,

With C++20, prefer requires over std::enable_if.

fwiw, more recent gcc has a more clear error message: https://godbolt.org/z/addafzTEo. Already with 10.2 you can remove sfinae to get the same error: https://godbolt.org/z/PGejzdGqa Though 10.2 seems to have a bug and accepts redifinition in the most simple case https://godbolt.org/z/14eEef18E. This seems to be fixed in more recent version https://godbolt.org/z/fMsMh9bbG

The error message describes the problem:

foo.cpp:20:30: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing 'typename std::enable_if<(TMethod == 1), void>::type SampleClass<TClass>::method1()'
   20 | SampleClass<TClass>::method1() {}
      |       


Specifically "default argument for template parameter" is the problem, which is what the error message points to.
The problem is the default argument.  You aren't allowed to put it here.
template <int TClass>
template <int TMethod /* = TClass*/>
typename std::enable_if<TMethod == 1, void>::type
SampleClass<TClass>::method1() {}

Just comment it out.
Generally repeating default arguments is banned in C++ to avoid making the compiler check that the two cases have the same value.
